# Program Not opening in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a very unusual problem. I have been running a program, OVITO, for 1+ years on my computer under my main username login. Yesterday, the program just stopped opening for some reason. If I go to another username login, I can get it to open but not under my main username login. Is it possible I blocked it somehow in Linux? If so, how would I unblock. Anyone know what could be the issue?

Comment: What's your Linux distro?

Comment: It is Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Have you checked this program's log file?

Comment: How? I am not familiar with Linux that much. I just really use it now to open a couple programs that I like running in it.

Comment: The program literally just hangs, I don't see any kind of error message. It is like something is blocking the program from opening

Comment: Do you have any saved data in OVITO that you would be upset losing?

Comment: No, I completely erased it and re-installed. Same issue if that is what you were thinking. I have re-installed it twice and no change

Comment: Can you open terminal, type `ls /var/log/ |grep -i ovito` and paste the the output (if any)?

Comment: no output when pasting that

Comment: is there a directory ~/.ovito ?  (It would be a hidden directory).  If that exists, rename [delete] the directory and re-install.  [ I've never used or heard of ovito, but this is a standard way of storing per user configs under Ubuntu ]

Comment: how would I check for this? If I do: cd ~/.ovito   I get no such file or directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good possibility that the `~/.config` folder has another folder called `Ovito`. Delete this folder and you can open ovito in the terminal again. This happened to me couple of times and deleting the folder `~/.config/Ovito` made `ovito` run properly again.

Comment: Hmmm, is that all you did? It opens ovito, but when I Try to load anything it crashes

Comment: My guess is that you should `sudo apt-get remove ovito`, `rm -fr ~/.config/Ovito` and `sudo apt-get install ovito`

Comment: This does not seem to work either. Whenever I open a file on my main account it just hangs and begins not responding. Other accounts work fine. Weird

Comment: Actually that's all I did. Does it at least open ovito? Does ovito hang after you try to load something?

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1: Diagnose issue**

1. Open Terminal
2. `ovito`
3. Note any error messages and attempt to resolve.

**Method 2: Clear Ovito data**

1. Open Terminal
2. `rm -rf ~/.config/Alexander\ Stukowski/`
3. Run OVITO again normally

Comment: There are no error messages. I tried the second approach and then tried opening ovito and it still hung.